# Java Stream Optional: How can I convert the multiple inner Optional present condition to Optional.flatMap()

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap, stream-operators

I am trying to convert the multiple Optional isPresent to Optional.flatMap but not getting on how to do that.

```
private Optional<Commit> getCommit1 (String id, Integer number) {
    **Optional<Revision> revision = repository.findById(id,number);
    if (revision.isPresent()) {
        Optional<Commit> commit = commitRepository.findById(revision.get().getCommitId());
        if (commit.isPresent()) {
            return commit;
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();**
}
```

I want convert the bold part into single Optional.flatMap
Can someone help here

Comment: It seems, you are looking for a "one-liner"? Something like `return repository.findById(id,number).map(Revision::getCommitId).flatMap(commitRepository::findById)`?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you should yous e the *flatMap* method. One way to do it would be like this:

```
repository.findById(id,number)
    .map(revision -> revision.getCommitId())
    .flatMap(commitId -> commitRepository.findById(commitId));
```

Additionally, you can use method references for the *map* and *flatMap* parameters, resulting in a more concise code:

```
repository.findById(id,number)
    .map(Revision::getCommitId)
    .flatMap(commitRepository::findById);
```